# How do I access onedrive in an automated fashion without user interaction?

Tags: python, onedrive

I am trying to access my own docs & spreadsheets via onedrive's api. I have:

```
import requests

client_id = 'my_id'
client_secret = 'my_secret'
scopes = 'wl.offline_access%20wl.signin%20wl.basic'
response_type = 'token' # also have tried "code"
redirect_uri = 'https://login.live.com/oauth20_desktop.srf'

base_url = 'https://apis.live.net/v5.0/'

r = requests.get('https://login.live.com/oauth20_authorize.srf?client_id=%s&scope=%s&response_type=%s&redirect_uri=%s' % (client_id, scopes, response_type, redirect_uri))
print r.text
```

(For my client I've also tried both "Mobile or desktop client app:" set to "Yes" and "No")

This will return the html for the user to manually click on. Since the user is me and it's my account how do I access the API without user interaction?

EDIT #1:
For those confused on what I'm looking for it would be the equivalent of Google's Service Account (OAuth2): https://console.developers.google.com/project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot "bypass" the user interaction.

However you are very close to getting it to work.  If you want to gain an access token in python you have to do it through the browser.  You can use the web browser library to open the default web browser.  It will look something like this (your app must be a desktop app):

```
import webbrowser    
webbrowser.open("https://login.live.com/oauth20_authorize.srf?client_id=foo&scope=bar&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https://login.live.com/oauth20_desktop.srf")
```

This will bring you to the auth page, sign in and agree to the terms (it will differ depending on scope).  It will direct you to a page where the url looks like:

`https://login.live.com/oauth20_desktop.srf?code=<THISISTHECODEYOUWANT>&lc=foo`

Copy this code from the browser and have your python script take it as input.

You can then make a request as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn631818.aspx#authcodegrant) using the code you received from the browser.

You will receive a response described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn631818.aspx#response)

Comment: You misunderstood my question...specifically Edit #1 and Edit #4.

Comment: I am unsure of what you are asking.  As I mentioned in my post there is no way to bypass user interaction, you must sign through the UI on login.live.com at some point. Is the app running on a server or just a script?  The method I have provided is for a local python script.  If you wish to have server to server communication your redirect URL provided in the query parameters must be pointing to your application.  It must also handle a code query parameter that you would use in the same way as described above.

Comment: "Two-legged OAuth," like what you're referring to with [Google Service Accounts](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount), is for apps to access their own data, not a user's data. In your case you're trying to make your app access a user's OneDrive data (you're the user), so it requires standard "three-legged OAuth" with user consent. You could go through the user consent process once, get a refresh token, and then get subsequent access tokens without user interaction. But the refresh token does expire after a year, so you'd need to go through the consent flow again.

Comment: @daspek...1 year expiration for the refresh token...is that documented anywhere?

Comment: @daspek Been searching their docs and can't find out the expiration for refresh tokens. http://cloud-elements.com/oauth-2-0-access-refresh-token-guide/ says 6 months (and is undocumented like your stmt). Which is it?

Comment: It's currently a year, but it's not documented because we don't want apps to take a hard dependency on it in case it breaks. Apps need to be resilient against invalid refresh tokens, and be able to ask users for consent if need be. Beyond expiry, we can invalidate the refresh token if the user changes their password, for example. Barring things like that, though, the token should last for a year. But if you keep updating it every time you refresh your access token, you get another year extension. So as long as you use your app, you can potentially go indefinitely long without user interaction.